# Why can't I rename package in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Why can't I change package name in intellij idea?

I want to change "java" package to something else, for example "junit" or "jtests":

[image]

But when I select *Refactor -> Rename* I wind up with the dialog window:

[image]

then I select *Rename current*, in the next window I enter desired package name:

[image]

and then, no matters whether I click *Refactor* or *Preview* button, nothing happens. Nothing at all: no errors, no warnings, no actions. Why can't I rename this package?

Comment: looks like youre using an old version of intellij - which version do you have? mine says "Rename package" / "Rename directory" in same refactor menu

Comment: @vikingsteve, it's IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.6

Comment: Ok thats a really old version. Do you have possibility to install latest? This function certainly works in `2017.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug of IntelliJ IDEA. I found the solution [on JetBrains forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206203469-Refactor-rename-stops-working). By invalidating the cache and restarting, I got the ability to rename this package.

Answer (score 0):

For me invalidation didn't work. I made a new package and temporarily moved the classes out of the package I wanted to rename. It would disapear when I would rename them, so I would create them again.

Answer (score 0):

Just a bug in intellij. Invalidate the caches and restart. [Here's how](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llD2Z.png), it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

**Only folders under java are part of the package qualified name.**

Example:
If you have a file in a folder located under app/src/main/java/com/my/package then the package will be *com.my.package*

So, you only want to change folders under java.

However, regarding the "com" folder, the IDE does not provide an option to refactor package name. In this case, you need to manually rename all code occurrences of the old folder and invalidate the cache after renaming the folder.

File > Invalidate caches... > Clear system

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to memory problem, after increasing memory (heap size) it solved.